# PHP Session login crossing between sites on same server

Tags: php, session, cross-domain

I have CentOS LAMP with multiple sites. I use PHP session variable for the log into the wesites. My problem is if you log into one site you can open another site on the same server and you will be logged in. The sites are completely separate so I want them to have to log into each separately. Each site has a different user DB.

Here are the session variables I am populating upon login.

```
$_SESSION["username"] = "$username";
$_SESSION["user_id"] = "$user_id";
$_SESSION["act_type"] = "$act_type";
```

I have created a a little sample so you can recreate the problem

There is 2 separate sites:
/var/www/html/site1
/var/www/html/site2

Each site has 2 pages index.php, secure.php
If I log into one I can open secure.php on the other site to.

***/var/www/html/site1/index.php***

```
<?php

session_start();

$user = 'jane';
$pass  = '654321';

if ( $user == $_POST[user] AND $pass == $_POST[pass] ) {

    $_SESSION[user] = $user;
    header("location: secure.php");
}
else {
    echo "Bad Login";
}

?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">

    Username: <input name="user" type="text">
    <br />
    Password: <input name="pass" type="password">
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

***/var/www/html/site1/secure.php***

```
<?php

session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION[user]) ) {

    header("location: index.php");
}

?>
Secure Page
```

***/var/www/html/site2/index.php***

```
<?php

session_start();

$user = 'joe';
$pass  = '123456';

if ( $user == $_POST[user] AND $pass == $_POST[pass] ) {

    $_SESSION[user] = $user;
    header("location: secure.php");
}
else {
    echo "Bad Login";
}

?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">

    Username: <input name="user" type="text">
    <br />
    Password: <input name="pass" type="password">
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

***/var/www/html/site2/secure.php***

```
<?php

session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION[user]) ) {

    header("location: index.php");
}

?>
Secure Page
```

Comment: The only way that would happen is if the sites have the same domain.

Comment: I currently don't have domains. One site is accessed by IP and the second site is access by IP/folder.

Comment: By default, the session cookie will cover the entire domain. Set `session.cookie_path` for each site. Should be done with ini_set within the site bootstrap or before the session is started.

Comment: how will that work with one site in the root folder and the other site is in a folder in that root. Should i just  put the sites in the in separate folders in the root and not have a site in the root?

Comment: If you are going to use folders, put the root site in its own folder and redirect to that from root.

Comment: I have tried putting `ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/site1/');` in site1 files and `ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/site2/');` in site2 files before `session_start()` and I am getting the same results.

Comment: Make sure you clear any existing session cookies while testing.

Comment: I just ran `session_destroy();` and tried again same results.

Comment: `session_destory` only clears data on the server, it does not delete the cookie. Using chrome developer tools/firecookie, you can see how the session cookie is configured and if the path is getting set.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted that cookie and it worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your having a collision between the session cookie settings. You should use either a separate php.ini file per site (if that's possible) or a particular setup at the entry point of every site. Take a look at http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: The cookie looks like it would work however I currently do not have domains to set in the cookie. Everything is access by IP.

Comment: Do you use IPbased virtualhosting? If so, perhaps you could try to use the IP as the cookie domain.

Comment: Everything is accessed through the same ip

Comment: Ok... so, how do you access a specific site? Do you use different ports? Or do you simply put in the whole path? if it's the latter, I'm affraid you are going to have to create a desambiguation mechanism (i.e. a different prefix in the session variables for every site), although, I wouldn't go down this road. My advice is that you have a look at virtual hosting configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation as yourself, two sites on the same server and using IP (company intranet). Had issue where they were crossing for login, and also destroying each other if you logged out on either. My solution was to use a prefix for the session variables to signify the individual sites.

**Session Variables**

**Site 1**

```
$_SESSION["s1_username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["s1_user_id"] = $user_id;
$_SESSION["s1_act_type"] = $act_type;
```

**Site 2**

```
$_SESSION["s2_username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["s2_user_id"] = $user_id;
$_SESSION["s2_act_type"] = $act_type;
```

^That will keep the login information separate between the two sites, so they won't "bleed" over to one another. But what about when we log out? Won't `session_destroy()` get rid of ALL of the variables? Here is what I did for that:

**Destroying Session / Logging Out**

**Site 1**

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
  if (strpos($key, 's1_') === 0)
  {
   unset($_SESSION[$key]);
  }
}
```

**Site 2**

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
  if (strpos($key, 's2_') === 0)
  {
   unset($_SESSION[$key]);
  }
}
```

^This prevented my websites from destroying each others variables if you logged out on one, and not the other.

Hope this helps someone out there not waste 6 hours like I did! :D

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
session_name( 'site1' );
session_start();
```

You're creating a session tuple like `site1.user` which is overriding *php.ini's* default `PHPSESSID`.

Call it on your logging page `index.php`,  `session.php` `logout.php`. This is most common login file skeleton or every time you call `session_start()`, `session_name(<sess_name>)` should precede.